# XAMPP and Memcache Install issue

Tags: php, memcached, xampp

I am trying to install Memcache on my local machine on xampp. When I got start Apache on the XAMPP Control Panel...this error appears..

```
PHP startup: memcache: Unable to initialize module Module complied with module API=20090626 PHP comiled with module API=20100525 These options need to match
```

What do I do to fix this and get memcache up and running?